# Extract L* component from image after converting from RGB to LAB

Tags: python, image, image-processing, scipy, scikit-image

I am trying to take an RGB image, convert it into LAB (aka CIE L* a* b*) colorspace, and extract the L* component.

Here is my code:

```
from skimage import io, color
from scipy import misc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

img = misc.imread("/Users/zheyuanlin/Desktop/opencv_tests/parrots.png", mode='RGB')
img_resized = misc.imresize(img, (256, 256), 'bilinear') # resized to 256x256

img_cielab = color.rgb2lab(img_resized, illuminant='D50')

# Rescale due to range of LAB values being L (0-100), a (-128-127), b (-128-127)
cielab_scaled = (img_cielab + [0, 128, 128]) / [100, 255, 255] 

cie_l, cie_a, cie_b = cv2.split(cielab_scaled)


""" Display the image """
plt.imshow(cie_l)
plt.show()
```

This is the image produced:
[image: This is the image shown by plt]

Here is an example of an L* component of the same image from a research paper I found on google:
[image]

I don't know why mine looks so green, does anyone know the problem with my code? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image you display is identical to the one from the paper. But pyplot has a default color map that adds blue, green and yellow to the gray-scale image.

To change the color map used, use [the `set_cmap` function](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.set_cmap.html#matplotlib.pyplot.set_cmap):

```
plt.set_cmap('gray')
```

Comment: bless your soul kind sir